# PHP : Uploading multiple files

Tags: php

trying to upload multiple files
Move_uploaded_file not working.
file permission user#777

```
$file = $_FILES['photo'];
$count = count($file['name']);
for($a = 0 ; $a<$count ; $a++)
{
echo  $_FILES['photo']['name'][$a];
$target_dir =  preg_replace('/\s+/', 
'',$name.'_'.basename($_FILES['photo']['name'][$a]));
$target_file = "../upload/".$target_dir;
echo $target_file;  
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']["name"][$a], $target_file))
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than ”not working”.

Comment: post your form code

Comment: <body>
        <form method="post" action="php/register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select sample photos"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Registration"><br>
        </form>
    </body>

Comment: showing error 22527

Answer (score 0):

You maybe pointing to the wrong path. Make it complete by using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

**This:**

```
$target_file = "../upload/".$target_dir;
```

**to:**

```
$target_file =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/".$target_dir;
```

The source file should be 'tmp_name' one, not the 'name'.

**From:**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']["name"][$a], $target_file)){
```

**To:**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"][$a], $target_file)){
```

If the above changes still don't fix it:

**Check your php.ini**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M


; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Comment: "tmp_name" worked thank you!!!